# Given a set of simultaneous equations find a solution for a given criteria, and by how much unknowns differ.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

Given:

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^2 - xy = 238\\\\
xy - y^2 = 189
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

by factorising the left-hand side of both equations we get

$$(x-y)^2  = 49$$

(a) Given that $x$ and $y$ are positive and $x > y$, find $x$ and $y$.

By trial and error I got $x = 34$ and $y = 27$.

What's the correct, elegant, mathematical approach to finding the solution?

(b) Consider the following simultaneous equations. By how much do $u$ and $v$ differ?

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
u^3 - 3u^2v = 16\\\\
v^3 - 3uv^2 = -11
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Does the information in question (a) provide any insight into solving (b)? Any tips to proceed?

Comment: Hint: A) The first equation is $ x (x-y) = 238$. Do you know what $x-y$ is? B) Consider $ (u + iv)^3$.

Comment: @CalvinLin (A) $x - y = 7$, hence $x = 238/7 = 34, y = 27 follows. A lot more practice required on my part. Thanks!

Comment: @CalvinLin I think you mean $(u-v)^3$ for the second question

Comment: @epiliam Nope, my hint was wrong because I didn't see the variables correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You are on the right track!

Let us tackle the item $(a)$ first.

Since $x > y$, we can rewrite the obtained relation as follows:

\begin{align*}
(x - y)^{2} = 49 & \Longleftrightarrow |x - y|^{2} = 49\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x - y| = 7\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x - y = 7\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x = 7 + y
\end{align*}

Now you can substitute such relation into the first or second equation given.

**EDIT**

According to the @epiliam's comment, we can apply an (easier) alternative approach:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
u^{3} - 3u^{2}v = 16\\\\
v^{3} - 3uv^{2} = -11
\end{cases} & \Rightarrow u^{3} - 3u^{2}v + 3uv^{2} - v^{3} = 27\\\\
& \Rightarrow (u - v)^{3} = 27\\\\
& \Rightarrow u - v = 3\\\\
& \Rightarrow u = 3 + v
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: You should write the second question as $u^3 - 3u^2v+3uv^2-v^3=(u-v)^3=27$. You're making it a lot harder than it is.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the comment. Although both ways work, it seems easier to apply your approach. I totally forgot to consider the remaining steps needed to solve the exercise. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Could anyone explain why the downvote?

Comment: If you think it was me, it wasn't

Comment: Thanks all. Long way to go before I can see these elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the first equation by the second to conclude that $189x=238y.$
So let $x=238t$ and $y=189t.$ Plugging these values into the first
equation gives $49t^2=1.$ Thus, $t={1\over7}$, $x=34$ and $y=27$.